# JQuery how to know when a new message is received?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

Im using the follow javascript in messages page, is it possible to play a sound when a new message is received? Be aware that i don't want to play a sound for each request but only when a new message is added in the page.

```
function homeAjax() {
  $.ajax({
    url : 'subHome',
    success : function(data) {
      $('#result').html(data);
    }
  });      
}

var intervalId = 0;
intervalId = setInterval(homeAjax, 3000);
```

My MVC controller (subHome) returns all messages using ModelAndView.

Comment: Then you'd first have to figure out when `data` contains new messages, wouldn't you, as now you're just outputting all messages on every single request ?

Comment: Java tag was removed as I don't see how this question relates to Java. If I'm wrong, please let me know.

Comment: @adeneo Yes, but how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe it will help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var datLength = 0;
  function homeAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url : '/data',
        contentType : "application/json",
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {

           if(data.length > datLength){
               console.log(data.length);
               datLength = data.length;
               /*jquery audio play*/
           }else{
               console.log("no play");
           }
        }
    });

    } 
 </script>
```

Show Console

[image]

Comment: That seems to do the job. Although i'd like to know if there is any better method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use an `<audio>` tag:

```
<audio id="myAudio" src="path/to/sound.mp3">
```

Then whenever you need to play the clip, use:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("myAudio").play();
</script>
```

Comment: The question is how to know when a new message is received. Sorry for misleading with the title